# Converting Tokens to crystals

Tags: firefall

In Firefall you can convert crystals into tokens at 25 crystals per token. I have accumulated a large amount of tokens after selling items. Is there any way to gain back some of my crystals or is the currency swap permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I know of is to buy things from the marketplace using the credits, and then salvage them.

The exchange rate is horrible, though.